# IMACROS - Infinit Loop

Tags: imacros

How do I get an infinite loop with this part of the code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:next
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

the complete code:

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=http://localhost/site/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:next
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:next
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just play the following macro in loop mode:

```
SET myUrl http://localhost/site/
SET curUrl EVAL("({{!LOOP}} == 1) ? '{{myUrl}}' : 'javascript: undefined';")
URL GOTO={{curUrl}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:next
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

If you want the loop to be "infinite" set the 'Max:' value to a very big number (e.g. 99999999999).

Comment: Thank you it works! I appreciate it if u can help me in another doubt [IF and ELSE - IMACROS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403649/if-and-else-imacros)